# Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hadoop2

Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator

Job running in-process (local Hadoop)

2017-03-23 12:19:17,371 Stage-1 map = 0%, reduce = 0%

Ended Job = job_local1571094051_0001 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:

Stage-Stage-1: HDFS Read: 16384 HDFS Write: 10596 FAIL

Comment: Can you provide the sample code you are trying to run..

Comment: Sure.I ll share the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013292/ended-job-job-local644049657-0014-with-errors-error-during-job-obtaining-debu

Answer (score 1):

set below property before inserting.

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition = true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode = nonstrict;
SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions = 10000;
SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode = 1000;
```

Comment: Bless you. Took me forever to stumble here and it worked!

Comment: it’s not working for my case. need help!