# Ended Job = job_local644049657_0014 with errors Error during job, obtaining debugging information

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

How to find the log file

Please guide

I have checked in the url of Resouce manager. But i didnt find any log file

This is the complete error

> Query ID = hadoop_20170325120040_d54d136a-1904-4af9-8f8d-4167343db072
>   Total jobs = 1 Launching Job 1 out of 1 Number of reduce tasks is set
>   to 0 since there's no reduce operator Job running in-process (local
>   Hadoop) 2017-03-25 12:00:42,954 Stage-0 map = 0%,  reduce = 0% Ended
>   Job = job_local644049657_0014 with errors Error during job, obtaining
>   debugging information...
>
> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
>   Stage-Stage-0:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL Total MapReduce CPU
>   Time Spent: 0 msec

I will share the configuration of my resource manager

Yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>impc2362.htcitmr:8022</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager-scheduler.address</name>
    <value>impc2362.htcitmr:8021</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Do i need to add any other property apart from the above given properties?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

```
yarn logs --applicationId <application_id_of_your_job>
```

Comment: Brother, Where can i get the application id of the job?

Comment: Hi Basil, Can you follow up on the console dump. Every yarn or azkaban applications comes with the application id and you can proceed from there. If you found my suggestions helpful, don't forget to appreciate my answers.

Comment: You can get it from the yarn UI or console dump or poll ambari server using REST API.